# python percentile centered in a 15 day window

Tags: python, window, percentile

I'm kind of new into Python functions and in general python (xarray for large data sets).
Does exist a function that can calculate the 90th percentile centered on a 15 day window for a long time series of a domain?

ie I have 62 years of daily maximum temperature during the summer season over North America (I merge with cdo the whole days within JJA). I want to calculate the 90th daily percentile of tmax (during the summer season) of the period based on a centered 15-day window (in order to calculate heat waves)

I was wondering if it exists something that can calculate directly this for a long time series? as in np.percentile? I was thinking if perhaps np.percentile has something like np.roll? but not sure how to use it properly

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is a very lengthy question and you seem to be asking multiple questions, and it’s hard to tell what the question is often. Can you please rewrite the question so that is about how to do things in CDO? Remember: this is a programming website, not a climate science website

Comment: still not quite sure what this question wants even after the edit. you want the 90th percentile in each 15 days segment?  i.e. calculated from 15 daily values? What is the output, a series of percentile values that changes daily timestep? Maybe you can give an example to illustrate as this question is very unclear.

Comment: Ok I edited the question, I can upload one year of the season to show how is my data? my data is from era5 but is daily data now since i applied cdo daymax to the hourly data

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use python, you can use:

```
ds = xr.open('file.nc')
ds_90p = ds.rolling(time=10, min_periods=1).construct('tmp').quantile(0.9, dim='tmp')
```

However this will take a very long time, depending on your PC, obviously. I strongly recommend using cdo which will yield the same result faster.

```
  cdo runpctl,90,10 input_file.nc output_file.nc
```